# Alerts Issue in sharepoint 2010

Tags: list

I created a alert for list using alert manager.But when alert mail will sent to the user,what ever columns are there in the list,that columns vales will sent only default values only.i want to send user selected values not default values.

Comment: Are you using a 3rd party alert manager? if not, did you create alert for the entire list or individual item(s)?